# How to import 12-bit tif image sequence in Video Editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, import, image, video, movie-clip-editor

I am having a sequence of tif files of 12-bit depth. When imported into blender  I am getting a blank screen. How to ensure that the images are imported properly into the video editor? I tried changing the input color format but with no success.

[image: Adding screenshot image for reference]

Answer (score 2):

According to the Blender Manual, 12-bit TIFF is not supported (but 8 and 16 bit TIFF is): https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/media/image_formats.html

I suggest converting the sequence to a different format (e.g. 16-bit TIFF, which is supported); there are several softwares that can achieve this. (I often use FFmpeg for this purpose—please let me know if you'd like help with FFmpeg.)

Comment: Thanks. I felt blender would auto convert the image to 16bit. Also, I'm more convinient with ImageJ; l'll be using it to convert the image to 16 bit.